# How to find coordinates of a link with a specific caption in an Electron desktop application from a testing application in C#

Tags: c#, electron, ui-automation

**Context:**

I am beginning to write a testing application in C# which, as part of testing, needs to do UI automation of another Windows desktop application written in Electron, to extract certain results and compare with expected output.

The Electron application has a few hyperlinks, and HTML style buttons, which I need to locate and click.
The Electron application is written by another team and I cannot ask them to include testing features in the UI.

**Question:**

**How can I dynamically find the position of the hyperlink with the text "Login" within the Electron application and click it from my C# application?**

I have been able to start the Electron application programmatically, bring it to foreground and send keystrokes to it. Now I need to click on the Login hyperlink.

I have read many similar questions but most are for testing native Windows applications.

**EDIT 1:**

If I loop over all the child windows of the Electron application, I find only 2 windows. It seems Electron does not render hyperlinks or other HTML elements as Windows.

If I use SendMessage to read the window text, it only returns "Chrome Legacy Window".

Comment: Which UI automation library are you using? You could look into integrating something like Selenium with [Electron ChromeDriver](https://github.com/electron/chromedriver) to be able to access the HTML DOM.

Comment: Not using any library. Attempting using Windows API in C#. Is it not possible using Windows API? Else will have to learn Selenium

Comment: @Erick how can I find coordinates of the link in Electron app and click it using Electron ChromeDriver, using C#?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with C#, but you would select the link using a CSS or xpath selector using the Selenium WebDriver, which in turn controls Electron ChromeDriver.

Comment: Yeah. This much I know. But I guess I have to wait for other answers as I need some help on using Electron ChromeDriver in C#